# Unable to install pip3 and easy_install on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python-3.x, pip, ubuntu-18.04, easy-install

My fresh Ubuntu 18.04 does not have pip3 installed and following multiple questions, I could only install it using easy_install3. However, easy_install3 is not available and instructions to install it are using pip3. I am in a deadlock now. My attempts:

1. `sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools` which is successful
2. `sudo easy_install3 pip`: `sudo: easy_install3: command not found`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try 
for python3 pip

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

for python 2.x pip

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

Comment: I downvoted because the end result is not the same. Using easy_install3 would install pip3 on the latest version (20.x currently), and installing python3-pip will provide version 9.x.